# Multiple JSONP XHR requests in AngularJS failing

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, jsonp

I have a web app that makes multiple XHR requests to different web services. I'm having issues making calls to the [Federal Register API](https://www.federalregister.gov/developers/api/v1).  From the documentation [here](https://www.federalregister.gov/blog/learn/developers) it suggests:

> A simple JSONP interface is also possible; simply add a `callback=foo`
>   CGI parameter to the end of any URL to have the results be ready for
>   cross-domain JavaScript consumption

Based on the [Angular docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) I need to use `&callback=JSON_CALLBACK`.

I've set this request up the exact same way as I have with other jsonp calls in this view, but the Federal Register call is returning an error `Unexpected token :`.  The JSON is coming through, and it's wrapped in a function defined by Angular: `articles.json?angular.callbacks._4`, which is what I'd expect.  Maybe I've made a simple mistake, but as far as I can tell this is set up just like my other XHR requests.

**From the Console:**

[image]

**My service:**

```
angular.module('atRiskApp.services')

.factory('FederalRegister', [ '$http', function ($http) {
    var searchRegisterByName = function ( sciName ) {
        var url = 'http://www.federalregister.gov/api/v1/articles.json?per_page=20&order=newest&conditions%5Bterm%5D=' + sciName + '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
        var promise = $http.jsonp( url );
        return promise;
    };

    return {
        searchRegisterByName: searchRegisterByName
    }
}]);
```

**Controller:**

```
FederalRegister.searchRegisterByName($scope.codes.sciName).then(function (response) {
  $scope.registerDocs = response.data;
});
```

**Edit:**
Here is the [URL for a sample API call](https://www.federalregister.gov/api/v1/articles.json?per_page=20&order=newest&conditions%5Bterm%5D=Solanum%20conocarpum&callback=JSON_CALLBACK).  The data is correctly wrapped in a JSON_CALLBACK(); what's wrong??

**Edit 2:**
The API has a [form for constructing API calls](https://www.federalregister.gov/developers/api/v1).  I see that the content-type returned by the API is `application/json` rather than `application/javascript` could this be causing a problem?

Comment: XHR and JSONP are mutually exclusive, use one or the other. to be fair, you can string-process the return to strip the JSONp part, but why bother?

Comment: I'm relatively new to ajax requests, so forgive my ignorance.  Why can't I get a hold of the response object in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the component that I was adding to the URL was not being encoded.  This led to a space being included in the API call.  For whatever reason the API call succeeded in returning JSONP, but I was still getting an error.

I switched the URL in my service to encode the scientific name before making the api call:

```
angular.module('atRiskApp.services')

.factory('FederalRegister', [ '$http', function ($http) {
    var searchRegisterByName = function ( sciName ) {
        var url = 'http://www.federalregister.gov/api/v1/articles.json?per_page=20&order=newest&conditions%5Bterm%5D=' + encodeURIComponent(sciName) + '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
        return $http.jsonp( url );
    };

    return {
        searchRegisterByName: searchRegisterByName
    }
}]);
```

The key bit being `encodeURIComponent(sciName)` in the url declaration.